Can I tell if a file format matches the expected format when reading it in Python?
I am writing a script that requires users place plain text FASTA format files in a directory. The script will call a subprocess that will fail if the file is not FASTA format and I would like to inform the user as to why the subprocess failed and the script exited.

Define "plaintext". Using a single-byte encoding like Latin-1, every possible byte maps to some character. Even a random binary file can be interpreted as text that way. It'll just be mostly garbage text. So at best you can take a statistic approach: either look for an abundance of NUL bytes, which you probably won't find in actual text files. Or apply [tag:nlp] to see if the text forms any sort of words you expect.

What you probably want is a whitelist approach: check if all characters in a file fall within your expected range of characters. If not, then the sequence doesn't make sense as a DNA sequence to you and is garbage to you.

Is the failing of the subprocess not a sufficient signal? Why do you want to check before the subprocess checks it as well? You could apply some heuristics to see if it is a text file, but then your subprocess might still fail (e.g. because the file isn't actually FASTA).

I was hoping to provide the user with some feedback as to why the script failed, I think a whitelist approach will work in this case since DNA sequence files are basically alphanumeric with very few special characters, thanks!

You might want to rephrase your question and caption, as it is actually not about arbitrary text content (which, as already discussed by deceze's comment, is virtually impossible to verify), but about a (more or less) specified file format (which might actually be verifiable).

Thanks, question and description edited to reflect the feedback

I recommend you to try to use a parser like this  and to assert the result.

Yes, this is a good idea as I'm already using Biopython to parse each file. Maybe I can raise an exception in the case that the parser fails, which is UnicodeDecodeError and make sure I do this step before running the subprocess.

You may want to validate your files using a python package called py_fasta_validator.  See this answer.
